# __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'op' and 'message'

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, anaconda, mnist

I am using TensorFlow 2.2 and Python 3.5. I am unable to load *MNIST* data set.

Code:

```
mnist_dataset, mnist_info = tfds.load(name='mnist', with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
```

Error:

> **init**() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'op' and 'message'

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend try downgrading to tensorflow-datasets==2.1.0.

- Go to Anaconda Prompt
- `pip install tensorflow-datasets==2.1.0`
- Restart kernel and then try your code again

```
mnist_dataset, mnist_info = tfds.load(name='mnist', with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
```